# How to show images in posts of Github pages created by jekyll?

Tags: git, image, github, repository, jekyll

I got a repo in Github. I created a static website for this repo using Jekyll. Here is the website: http://andrewhzau.github.io/RICENCODE/. I created some .md files in the _posts directory. Everything is okay except that the figures are not shown correctly.

Here is one of my .md file:

```
---
layout: post
title: "GSD1"
description: ""
category: genes
tags: [grain setting, photoassimilate translocation, plasma membrane, grain filling]
---
{% include JB/setup %}

........

## Key figures
![Expression]({{ site.url }}/assets/images/GSD1.exp.png)  
![Phenotype]({{ site.url }}/assets/images/GSD1.pheno.png)
```

And here is the generated page for this post:

```
http://andrewhzau.github.io/RICENCODE/genes/2014/09/20/GSD1/
```

On my local computer, I use "jekyll serve" to generate the website and access it using

```
http://localhost:4000/
```

and the figures are okay.

Can you guys help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to set the `site.JB.BASE_PATH` parameter in `_config.yml` :

```
BASE_PATH : /RICENCODE
```

Then call your images like this :

```
![GSD1 phenotype]({{ BASE_PATH }}/assets/images/GSD1.pheno.png)
```

Comment: I tried BASE_PATH but it wouldn't work. It was:  BASE_PATH: http://andrewhzau.github.io/RICENCODE. I changed BASE_PATH to /RICENCODE. It works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem, my `kitty image` shown cutely in localhost but missing in github pages with 404 error and the pathname is incorrectly missing `baseurl`. I solved it in [kitty-image-problem-solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69954620/kitty-image-is-missing-in-welcome-to-jekyll-post-but-shown-at-index-md-and-about.md).

In short, in order for your /assets/images/GSD1.exp.png to show up in your _posts/ posts, you should do

```
   ![Expression]({{ "/assets/images/GSD1.exp.png" | relative_url }})
```

The document of `relative_url` is at [jykyll-liquid-filters](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)

Answer (score 0):

I used the full URL and the figures were shown correctly.

```
## Key figures
<img src="http://andrewhzau.github.io/RICENCODE/assets/images/GSD1.pheno.png" >  
<img src="http://andrewhzau.github.io/RICENCODE/assets/images/GSD1.exp.png" >
```

The figures won't behave properly on my local computer. Anyway, the problem was solved as long as it is okay with the website in the internet.