# Kitty image is missing in 'Welcome to Jekyll' post but shown at index.md and about.md

Tags: image, localhost, jekyll, github-pages, relative-url

My goal is to display an image in posts using Jekyll + Github Pages. I ran into 404 error and the image did not show. My repo is at https://github.com/kuolai/blogubb. The site is at https://kuolai.github.io/blogubb. If you go to **the site**, you will see a kitty image at the home page. But if you go to the post `Welcome to Jekyll`, there is no image!!

Steps I did to create remote repo and the site:

1. `gihub.com/new` to create a remote repo
2. The local repo was created with `jekyll new blogubb`
3. _config.yml with one line change `baseurl: "blogubb"
4. The photo is a cute kitty stored in assets/img/kitty.png
5. The only post, the default post, 2021-11-13-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown, with one line added `![](/assets/img/kitty.png)`
6. `git checkout -b "gh-pages"`
7. `git remote add origin .../blogubb.git`
8. `git push origin gh-pages`

Other than kitty image not shown in `Welcome to Jekyll` post, everything looks good.
I also tried

- localhost:4000, and it worked
- `![](/assets/img/kitty.png)` at home page `index.markdown`, and it worked
- `![](/assets/img/kitty.png)` at about page `about.markdown`, and it worked
- even https://github.com/kuolai/blogubb/blob/gh-pages/_posts/2021-11-13-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown worked at repo

The error message from the console of Chrome DevTools:

```
GET https://kuolai.github.io/assets/img/kitty.png 404
welcome-to-jekyll.html:50
```

To make a minimum case, I was able to re-create the problem with minimal lines of changes. Please help.

Comment: The full path name in the error message showed a clue that `![](assets/img/kitty.png)` relative link was not expanded correctly. It should be kuolai.github.io/assets/img/blogubb/kitty.png but instead kuolai.github.io/assets/img/kitty.png sadly without baseurl.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Replace

```
![](/assets/img/kitty.png)
```

with

```
![]({{"/assets/img/kitty.png" | relative_url }} )
```

The document of Liquid Filters is in https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/